# Integrating C# & C++ application using secured COM via referenced C++ .TLB

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I'm trying to get my C#4.0 (VS2010) app to interact with a C++ app using COM and a referenced type library.

All the examples I've seen using third-party libraries mostly include ActiveX controls or dll's where you can simply add a reference and create objects. I'm unable to create any objects directly (I get an error saying to use the interface instead) and I'm unable to find anything that will return the interface.

This is a secure COM library for accessing an encrypted database and requires a passphrase when creating the instance.

I've spent a lot of time on this to know generally what needs to be done but also enough to realize that it is obscure enough that I'm not going to figure it out in a reasonable time period. The closest examples I've found are very abstract and undocumented. It might be useful for someone who understands COM and reflection and interop very well but is insufficient to use as a starting point with my experience.

I'm stuck at the point where I have a single method to call but I feel months away from being able to call it.

---

The C++ app was built in release mode using VS2005 and the .tlb was successfully added as a reference to my C# 2010 solution. The C++ application is installed on my development machine.

In the object browser I can see public class SecureRepositoryClass, member of SecurityAgentLib, with method GetPolicyValue(string,string,string) that I want to call. This implements ISecureRepository which defined GetPolicyValue.

I know something is supposed to return a reference I can cast to ISecureRepository and then call the method I need.

What I can't figure out how to do is to get a reference to this. Our C++ project (written by someone else, I'm not a C++ developer unfortunately) uses the following code (with variables that are set in another context)

```
   HRESULT hr = CoGetClassObject(CLSID_SecureRuntimeAgent, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, NULL, IID_IClassFactory2, (void**) &pClf);

   if ((SUCCEEDED(hr)))
   {
         CComBSTR bstrKey = (LPCTSTR)ProduceKey();
         hr = pClf->CreateInstanceLic(NULL, NULL, IID_ISecureRuntimeAgent, bstrKey, (void**)&m_pIAPLI);
         if ((!SUCCEEDED(hr)))
```

I've searched for CreateInstanceLic, CoGetClassObject, and have been trying to find C# equivalents.

I've tried several examples but without really understanding what they mean it is hard to adapt to this particular situation.

I know what I have, and what I need, but not how to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear that the IClassFactory2 COM interface is implemented in the standard run time callable wrapper, so it looks like you are going to have to do it the brute force way and call the unmanged api in Ole32.dll from your managed code. There is an example of doing that in C# here http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/28/144657.aspx . I am hesitant to copy that code directly here since no copyright terms are specified for that code.

Comment: A lot of this doesn't mean much to me but I gave it a shot. I found ISecureRuntimeAgent's Guid in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface. I replaced 'gd = new guid' with the value from the registry. This example has 3 Guid's in it, I'm not sure which one(s) to replace but I figured at least that one. They're all different. I also added const LOCAL_SERVER=4 instead of INPROC_SERVER=1 which is what the C++ code I have uses. When it calls CoGetClassObject it throws error REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG with HRESULT 0x80040154. I've seen a few examples like this but haven't been able to make the customizations required.

Comment: That is a generic class not registered exception, so no help from google on that one. I didn't expect it to work I'm just not sure what to change next.

Comment: You don't need the guid for the ISecureRuntimeAgent, that is the GUID for the interface (aka you need that for a query interface call). The only guid you need to change in the example is the Guid (gd) in main. That is the GUID of the class factory. It needs to be the same guid as CLSID_SecureRuntimeAgent in you C++ example. You will also find it as a key in your registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID

Comment: Made some progress. I got the right Guid (That was CLSID_SecureRuntimeAgent) and got past the CoGetClassObject call once I changed to LOCAL_SERVER from INPROC_SERVER. In the CreateInstanceLic call, using IID_IUnknown, I'm able to cast ppval to (SecurityAgentLib.ISecureRepository), but not (SecurityAgentLib.ISecureRuntimeAgent) which is what I need. I was able to successfully call a method on the first interface though, so I got past the license query. I just need to figure out how to cast to the right interface. I'm told by our C++ guy there are 2 interfaces and IID_Unknown goes to one

Comment: In the original source code there is IID_ISecureRuntimeAgent, so if I can figure out what that value is hopefully that is what I need. I've tried a few random Guid's but haven't come across the right one yet, I keep getting an invalid cast exception during the CreateInstanceLic call

Comment: Have you tried changing the guid in the CreateInstanceLic from the guid of IUnknow to the guid of the ISecureRuntimeAgent ? Basically changing IID_IUnknown to IID_ISecureRuntimeAgent.

Comment: I searched HKCR for ISecureRuntimeAgent and found it as the 'Data' value for key {5FB4FC87-3328-4EC0-A838-37F15E64052D}, so I tried that. That key also had a TypeLib child key with a Default value of {F5E84276-5789-4114-8773-02BB8DF2C6D8}, so I tried that too. I also tried several other guid's from other parts of the registry that had anything to do with the RuntimeAgent but I always get a InvalidCastException:Specfied cast is not valid error on CreateInstanceLic.

Comment: With the IID_IUnknown that was there I can cast to ISecureRepository but if I attempt to cast to ISecureRuntimeAgent I get System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'SecurityAgentLib.ISecureRuntimeAgent'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{5FB4FC87-3328-4EC0-A838-37F15E64052D}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: The developer, before he left, said that the first interface gave a reference to the second interface. We're going to look at it again Monday. I was able to get some real data back from the first interface so I feel like I'm getting pretty close to being there. This is kind of silly and not particularly intuitive though.